# Python Dictionary / List Comprehension for highly nested data

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

I've got a bunch of json returning from an API request that's structured (I think) as a dictionary containing lists where most of the data I need is in the first list, and that list in turn contains dictionaries for each item I'm evaluating, with the first item being a simple key:value pair identifying the item, and the second item being a key:value pair where the key is a reference to the relationship in the source data, and the value is another list, which contains a dictionary for each entry/attribute.

I might have screwed that up, but this is exactly what it looks like. The values for 'class_id' are all unique, and the values for 'tag_id' are unique within the subset, but can repeat or (as in the case of empty brackets in the first entry) not be present at all.

```
{'Data': [{'class_id': 'class_000',
       'relationship_id': []},
      {'class_id': 'class_001',
       'relationship_id': [{'tag_id': 'tag_000'},
                           {'tag_id': 'tag_001'},
                           {'tag_id': 'tag_002'},
                           {'tag_id': 'tag_003'},
                           {'tag_id': 'tag_004'}]},
      {'class_id': 'class_002',
       'relationship_id': [{'tag_id': 'tag_000'},
                           {'tag_id': 'tag_003'},
                           {'tag_id': 'tag_055'},
                           {'tag_id': 'tag_777'},]}],
'ResponseCode': 200, 'ResponseText': 'OK'}
```

What I need is to pass the class_id and the tag_id to a variable for each instance. So my desired output would be something that gets the first pair and sets it to a variable so I can evaluate it, then does the next, and so on until the last pair had been reached.

UPDATE: I posted the actual function this is currently going to for better context, I have to use the variables in MySQL commands, in this case, 'a_class_id' and 'a_tag_id':

```
data = json_response['Data']           
for data_subset in data:
a_class_id = data_subset['class_id']
relationship_subset = data_subset['relationship_id']
count = 0

for tag_total in relationship_subset:
    tag_total = relationship_subset[count]
    count = count + 1
    a_tag_id = tag_total['tag_id']
    cursor.execute("SELECT event_key FROM events WHERE source_unique_id='{}'".format(a_class_id))
    fetched_event_key = cursor.fetchone()

    if fetched_event_key != None:
        matched_event_key=(fetched_event_key[0])
        else: pass

    cursor.execute("SELECT tag_key FROM tags WHERE source_unique_id='{}'".format(a_tag_id))
    fetched_tag_key = cursor.fetchone()
    matched_tag_key = (fetched_tag_key[0])
    cursor.execute("SELECT event_tag_key FROM event_tags WHERE event_tags.event_key='{}' AND event_tags.tag_key='{}'".format(matched_event_key,matched_tag_key))
    matched_event_tag_key = cursor.fetchone()
```

I know the better way to do this is with dictionary / list comprehensions. I just can't figure out how to work one out with this much nested switching between dicts/lists. (I just started learning Python this month.) Is this possible?

Comment: Pretty sure you're going to need `for` loops anyway. Are you trying to avoid them altogether? How are you currently doing it?

Comment: Added some more context - I do have some other for loops (and if/else, too) and I don't mind them, of course, I'm just trying to figure out if there is a better way of retrieving the values than iterating through via COUNT or whatever, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume you have a function `do_something` that takes a class name and tag name

```
def do_something(klass, tag):
    ...
```

Then, you can evaluate this for all of the class and tag combinations in youe given data structure using:

```
results = [do_something(klass["class_id"], tag["tag_id"]) 
           for klass in data["Data"] for tag in klass["relationship_id"]]
```

For example if `do_something` is simply

```
>>> def do_something(klass, tag):
...     return "{}:{}".format(klass, tag)
```

Then

```
>>> [do_something(klass["class_id"], tag["tag_id"])
... for klass in data["Data"] for tag in klass["relationship_id"]]
['class_001:tag_000', 'class_001:tag_001', 'class_001:tag_002', 'class_001:tag_003', 'class_001:tag_004', 'class_002:tag_000', 'class_002:tag_003', 'class_002:tag_055', 'class_002:tag_777']
```

Comment: I'm sure this is right but it occurs to me I need to show how I'm using those variables more specifically, because I don't know the syntax well enough yet to use your answer I'll post an update, thank you.

Comment: long delay but this was the correct method, had to re-write some stuff to optimize for doing it this way - thanks!